# PC -> TV HDMI suddenly doesn't work, any other option does

Tags: hdmi

So my parents wanted to connect their PC to their TV, so they bought a 10m (35 ft) cable. It all worked perfectly. Then my mom tripped over the cable, breaking it. She somehow got a free replacement, but at the same time some more expensive one from an uncle.

Now the problem is that this suddenly doesn't work anymore (TV saying "Format not supported"). I've tried several other things to pinpoint the actual problem, but none brought me something conslusive:

```
PC (hdmi) to TV doesn't work (both cables)
PC (hdmi) to TV doesn't work (short cable)
Laptop (hdmi) to TV work (same cables)
BluRay (hdmi) to TV works (same cables)
PC (hdmi) to monitor works (same cables)
PC (DVI w/ adapter HDMI) to TV works (same cables)
```

I've tried different ports, tried Linux, reinstalling drivers (the graphics card is internal using an i5 sandy bridge. Normally it's running Windows 7 Home Prem, the TV being a Philips 37PFL7605H).

So basically, everything works, except that thing what we want. The only things I am thinking of is that the sound is interfering or that the HDMI-output is somehow broken. Or is it anything else? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Good troubleshooting.  You demonstrate that every item works at least in one instance.  Only the one combination does not work.  What is wrong with using the DVI/HDMI adapter at the PC (the last line of test results)?

Comment: Connecting the HDMI cable to the DVI port works, but that doesn't transfer any sound. I'd have to get extra sound cables to get that to the TV.
Which was one of the reasons to take HDMI, because that's the all-in-one package.

Comment: *"doesn't transfer any sound"* - Guess that depends on the GPU.  I've gotten video and 2-channel audio from the DVI port of some Nvidia GPUs (GeForce 8100 and 8200).  The audio does have to be enabled from the Nvidia control panel (which calls it an "HDMI port" even though it's a DVI connector).

Comment: If the GPU has an internal HD sound driver thing, it is a seperate "sound device" (hardware) in the system, it has to be enabled , driver installed, and the sounds "directed to it".  If it is only a sound problem, the "works ,doesnt work" list, could use more info on what of it does not work? Different TVs can be pickey about the resolutions it will work with, so always try HD specific reses when setting-up (then adjust later), like 1280x720x60 1920x1080x60

Comment: The GPU is the internal one, so unless the Intel HD audio can be set up to transfer DVI, there is no way to add the sound the same was as with Nvidia.
I'll try to set up anything with the DVI again, if you say the sound should be able to work.
I've tried different drivers for the video/sound and multiple resolutions, but it's always the same. Also, before everything worked so I assume it's not like the TV suddenly got picky. I'll check the HDMI output port too, maybe there's something broken.
Thanks.

Comment: @xslicer ohhh, so the only thing that changed is the cable, I was not quite sure what got changed , or what got broken. If your getting some AorV signals down an HDMI then you should be getting All the A&V that are sent down that cable?  http://www.hdmi.org/pdf/whitepaper/SilicaonImageHDMIWhitePaperv73(2).pdf  see pages 9-11, the audio is shoved into the blanking for the video.  So as best as I can tell, if they broke the ports, the Jack on either side , or the cable, it should be all or nothing?  I am still unclear on if you have an audio problem, or a complete fail?

Comment: It's a complete fail. The TV just says "Input not supported".

Since connecting the PC to another monitor works and using it over DVI to the TV works as well, it has to be something with the HDMI port and the TV. It's not really an issue with sound I think, that was just a possibility since DVI works. Regardless, I cannot add the sound to the DVI, you really need a video card for that in the GTX200+ range.

Comment: "Input not supported". sounds as if the cable is working. A signal is arriving at the TV. It is just not in the right format (resolution?) which the TV supports. Could you test witha HDMI monitor instead?  (not sure how tripping over a cable would have reset or changed those values though).